# Приоритет таймаутов в NGINX?

Tags: nginx

Значения по умолчанию:

```
client_header_timeout 60s;
client_body_timeout 60s;

lingering_time 30s;
http2_recv_timeout 30s;

keepalive_timeout 75s;
http2_idle_timeout 3m;

send_timeout 60s;
```

Предлагаемая конфигурация:

```
client_header_timeout 10s;
client_body_timeout 10s;

lingering_time 10s;
http2_recv_timeout 10s; 

keepalive_timeout 10s; # <-- будут ли эти директивы иметь приоритет над прочими?
http2_idle_timeout 10s; # <-- будут ли эти директивы иметь приоритет над прочими?

send_timeout 10s;
```

Comment: Непонятный вопрос. Эти таймауты не пересекаются во времени с остальными.

Comment: Почему не пересекаются? Получение заголовка и тела, доп. данных и отправка - всё осуществляется после установки соединения, а значит в рамках `keepalive_timeout` или `http2_idle_timeout`. Или они начинают отсчёт уже после после отправки запроса/ответа?

Comment: Keepalive timeout запускается после окончания ответа сервера.

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо.